# eclipse and codeigniter

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter

I am new to using eclipse for php and am struglling with something that should be very simple.

I use codeigniter - how can i add my codeigniter project to a new project in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to import your existing php project in eclipse mars

Step 1: Create a new php project in eclipse

Step 2: Place your project(code-igniter) folder into htdocs(in case of xampp)

Step 3: Right click on the project and select "Import..."

Step 4: Select "File System" and click next

Step 5: Browse the project path in "From Directory" Field

Step 6: Browse the project created in step 1 in "Into Folder" field

Step 7: Optional but important to note: If you want to connect to the project in htdocs, click "Advanced" and check the "Create links in workspace" checkbox and then finish or else, a copy of the project will be created in your current work-space.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your websites code into one folder, then boot eclipse.  When eclipse finishes booting to the work bench, go to: FILE -> IMPORT..., a dialog box appears, navigate through the tree: GENERAL -> EXISTING PROJECTS INTO WORKSPACE, then click Next and browse to the file location of your project folder, select the folder and click finish.  Viola`

Or if you already have a project in eclipse that you want to add codeigniter to, just copy the codeigniter folders into that projects folder, then go back to eclipse and F5 to refresh or select Refresh from:  FILE->REFRESH, when you have the project explorer pane open and selected. (You don't have to use a special button click within eclipse to add a folder/file to your project.  For eclipse to recognize it, just refresh the view after you add the folder and you will see it show up.  This one tripped me up when I switched from visual studio to eclipse.)